# How should exceptions to User Role Permissions be handled?

Tags: security, permissions, authorization, roles

Imagine a web security system that is made up of 5 tables that handle the authorization part of a web app:

1. Users
2. Roles
3. Permissions
4. rolePermissions (many-to-many between Roles and Permissions)
5. userRoles (many to many between Users and Roles)

Sometimes a User needs to be granted access to a Permission rule for a short amount of time and then removed again, such as when someone goes away for vacation and someone else needs to take over one of his tasks. The short answer is to create a new Role, assign that Role to the User and when that Role is no longer needed, either remove that Role from the User or delete it completely.

I would rather not have to create Roles all the time for something like that. One solution that has been suggested is to have a separate table called userPermissionChanges, which will record the:

1. userID
2. PermissionID
3. addDenyFlag (bit NOT NULL)

The addDenyFlag will be true if this is an extra Permission to be added to the user and false if it's a Permission that needs to be removed. Upon querying and caching a User's Permissions at the server scope, we would also include/exclude the changes table and make the necessary changes to each user's Permissions.

The suggested solution would theoretically work, but I am not so sure it's a good way of dealing with this problem. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to best go about this instead? Is there a standard that I should follow for such scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a standard that I should follow for such scenarios?

Yes there is. What you are trying to do is implement your own authorization logic in a decoupled way from your actual application. This is called **externalized authorization management**.

There is a standard called XACML - short for eXtensible Access Control Markup Language - that has been developed by OASIS over the last 10+ years. What does XACML give you?

1. an architecture with an authorization engine you query for decisions, an enforcement point which queries the engine and enforces the decision. The enforcement point protects your app, and a management component where you can manage all your authorization logic.
2. a policy language with which to define your authorization requirements such as the temporary access one you have.
3. a request / response format you use to create authorization requests and responses.

XACML implements a model called attribute-based access control (ABAC as defined here by NIST) and uses policies to express authorization constraints.

Example:

- a user with the *role=manager* can do the *action=view* on items of *type=blog post*.

The use case you have deals with both temporary assignments and proxy-delegation use cases. You could implement the former as follows:

- have a table called temporaryRole with 2 fields: the role name and the expiry date.
- your rule would become:

  - a user with the *temporary role=manager* can do the *action=view* on items of *type=blog post* if and only if *expiry date>current date*

The latter scenario would require

- a table with 2 fields: user id and delegate id.
- a new rule: a user with *role=manager* or a user who is a *delegate of a manager* can do the *action=view* on items of *type=blog post*.

Action, role, delegate, item type are all attributes. There is no limit to how many attributes you can use. All you have to figure out is where to read them from.

There are several benefits to using XACML:

- it's standards-based
- it can grow to cater for new scenarios. The model you have now (home-grown, implemented) doesn't cater for your proxy-delegation or for your temporary permissions so you have to reimplement parts of your framework. XACML would alleviate that for you.
- you can apply it to APIs, ESBs, web services, applications, and even databases...
- it's technology-neutral: it'll work in Java, .NET, Python...

Check out my [SlideShare account](http://www.slideshare.net/DavidBrossard/) for more info or my [blog](http://www.webfarmr.eu) for examples.